# Get position after filtering Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with searchview.

In each row I add checkbox for multiple select. But when I want to search something, and I check some rows. And when I return back to all rows positions mixes all.

I add getItemViewType and getItemId  in adapter but nothing happened

When filtering recyclerview I get wrong positions

MyAdapter class

```
public class ExpandableListSearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandableListSearchAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<RowModel> contactList;
    private List<RowModel> contactListFiltered;
    private Context context;
    private int type;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textName;
        public AppCompatCheckBox checkBox1;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textName = view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            checkBox1 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        }
    }

    ExpandableListSearchAdapter(Context context, List<RowModel> contactList, int type) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList = contactList;
        this.type = type;
        this.contactListFiltered = contactList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExpandableListSearchAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_searched_recycler_checkbox, viewGroup, false);
        return new ExpandableListSearchAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExpandableListSearchAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        final RowModel contact = contactListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(contact.getText());

        holder.checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkItem(position, holder);
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkItem(int position, MyViewHolder holder) {
        RowModel rm = contactListFiltered.get(position);

        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                if (holder.checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                    holder.checkBox1.setChecked(true);
                    UsedDatasSearch.addToListSearchedComputer(rm);
                }else{
                    holder.checkBox1.setChecked(false);
                    UsedDatasSearch.removeToListSearchedComputer(rm);
                }
                break;
             case 2:
                if (holder.checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                    holder.checkBox1.setChecked(true);
                    UsedDatasSearch.addToListSearchedComputerCpu(rm);
                }else{
                    holder.checkBox1.setChecked(false);
                    UsedDatasSearch.removeToListSearchedComputerCpu(rm);
                }
                break;
        }


    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    contactListFiltered = contactList;
                } else {
                    List<RowModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (RowModel row : contactList) {

                        if (row.getText().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    contactListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<RowModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Screenshot  step by step

[image: all records]

when i filter some row

[image: search some row]

and after all I reset filter

[image: reset filter]

Comment: Where do you store checked state? Why you don't restore it during `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: I store only values when checked checkbox.

Comment: There are a lot of answers on how to handle `CheckBox` state in `RecyclerView`, in short your `onBindViewHolder` must modify all the views - assuming it could have been bound before. Also you should never return `position` in `getItemViewType` and `getItemId`, this is a very dirty workaround used by people that don't understand how `RecyclerView.Adapter` works.

Comment: keep 2 different list for your adapter. One which contains all data and one which contains filtered data. When filtering pass the filtered list to the adapter and when cleared pass the all data list

Comment: @VivekMishra There have contactList and contactListFiltered. But it is only for filter

Answer (score 0):

try to make your holder final and after that write this code:

```
 holder.checkBox1.setTag(position);

 holder.checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos = (int)view.getTag();
            checkItem(pos, holder);
        }
    });
```

replace contactlistfiltered to contactlist:

```
  private void checkItem(int position, MyViewHolder holder) {
    RowModel rm = contactList.get(position);
```

Comment: please check now